# Can someone help me with the meaning of なすすべもなく in this sentence

Tags: grammar

> 奇襲をうけた僕はなすすべもなく敗北してしまい....その後肉体を陵辱されてしまった

Japandict.com, gives these meanings:
なすすべもなく = having no choice, at a loss for what to do, at one's wits' end, helpless

But would like more context to understand it, for example I see the words:

なす＝為す, the particle も, the negative form of なく＝ない

I don't know if I'm right

Comment: I'm not too sure what your question is but perhaps it might help that this is sometimes written as 為す術もない

Answer (score 3):

To break down:

- [なす (為す in kanji)](https://jisho.org/word/%E7%82%BA%E3%81%99): to do; to achieve; to carry out
- [すべ (術 in kanji)](https://jisho.org/word/%E8%A1%93-1): way; method; means
- も: even
- なく (continuative form of ない): not having ～; there being no ～

A literal translation is "there being no means which one (can) try". も is optional, so you can say なすすべなく, too.

That said, なすすべ(も)なく is basically a set phrase that can be (and should be) remembered as is.